# Fluid Content repeating after 4.3.4 update

Tags: fluid-field

Working on a client site (local MAMP), after updating to EE 4.3.4 fluid fields are repeating.

At the present I am using WYGWAM for RTE and the template allows for several types of fields, I have seen this behavior with both WYGWAM and standard textarea fields (have not tried others). Here is a excerpt of my template;

```
{fluid_content}
    {if content_rte}{content_rte}{/if}
    {if content_code}{content_code}{/if}
    {if figure}
    <figure>
        {figure}
        <figcaption>{figcaption}</figcaption>
    </figure>
    {/if}
    {if youtube_video_id}
    <div class="video_wrapper">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/{youtube_video_id}?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    {/if}
    {if embed_code}{embed_code}{/if}
{/fluid_content}
```

Once I load the page however, the content is displayed twice. This started happening this morning after updating EE.

Is this happening to anyone else?

Thanks

Comment: Okay I have found that because the textarea field is called "{content_code}" that it is causing some type of conflict. But renaming it to something like "{content_html}" or even "{cont_html}" does not solve the issue, it need be completely renamed.